# java.lang.ArrayStoreException: when assigning value with incorrect type to Object[] array

Tags: java

I come from a C background. It doesn't make sense to me that I can't add an `Object` to a `Object[]` in `foo()`.

I would expect the code in function `foo` to work at runtime but fail in `main()` when I attempt to do `strings[0].toLowerCase();` because the object in `strings[0]` is not a `String` but is actually a `StringBuilder` which doesn't have a `toLowerCase()`. At the end of the day, I am storing a pointer into an array of pointers and the line `objects[0] = other` should not be invalid. It is clear my understanding of java is wrong (but I an fairly new at the moment).

```
class Main {

    static void foo(Object[] objects, Object other) {
        objects[0] = other;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = { "stringValue" };
        foo(strings, new StringBuilder());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks all for the answer. I googled "java covariance of arrays" thanks to @Andy Turner and came across [this](http://www.programmr.com/blogs/two-things-every-java-developer-should-know-about-arrays) which discusses this behaviour. The trick is that the compiler and runtime treat the code very differently. Compiler is fine with the code, runtime isn't.

Comment: You are assigning an instance of `StringBuilder` to an array of `String`. This is incorrect.

Comment: I am assinging an `Object` to another `Object`. This should be valid. All function `foo` says is "Take this Object reference and add it to this array". I agree, later, when I cast it back to `String[]` and attempt to call a `String` method on a `StringBuilder` object it should fail.

Comment: @s5s `strings` is a `String[]`, not an `Object[]`. If you call `foo(...)`, it gets upcasted to an `Object[]`, but as soon as you try to store something to this array that isn't a `String`, you will get an `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: The ArrayStoreException is the perfect one for this.

Comment: This is a great example of why covariance of arrays was a design error.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for they keyword (covariance of arrays). I found this which is useful: http://www.programmr.com/blogs/two-things-every-java-developer-should-know-about-arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) of `ArrayStoreException`:

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following code generates an ArrayStoreException:

```
Object x[] = new String[3];
x[0] = new Integer(0);
```

Just because you're passing a `String[]` into a method that expects an `Object[]` doesn't mean that it's actually an `Object[]`.  Because you create a `String[]`, you can only add instances of `String` to it, and you're trying to add a `StringBuilder`, which doesn't make sense.

Notice how it does not throw an exception if you change the type of `String[]` to `Object[]`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] strings = { "stringValue" };
    foo(strings, new StringBuilder()); // Perfectly fine
}
```

Comment: So the JVM is doing runtime type checks? I would expect `objects[0] = new StringBuilder()` to not fail but later on, if I attempted to call a `String` method on `strings[0]` I would get a crash because the pointer does not actually point to a `String`

Comment: I haven't read enough about the JVM to tell you, but that certainly sounds like the case.  Seeing as you come from a C background, Java is different in that it normally doesn't let users make these mistakes.

Comment: The check is described in [the language specification of the simple assignment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1): "A Java compiler may be able to prove at compile time that the array component will be of type TC exactly (for example, TC might be final). But if a Java compiler cannot prove at compile time that the array component will be of type TC exactly, then a check must be performed at run time to ensure that the class RC is assignment compatible (§5.2) with the actual type SC of the array component."

Answer (score 1):

It is evaluated at runtime that your String Array is in fact trying to assign a different type.  You would an `ArrayStoreException`, which clearly says that

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong
>   type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following
>   code generates an ArrayStoreException:

```
Object x[] = new String[3];
 x[0] = new Integer(0);
```

It is not generally a good practice to accept Object types as parameters or even return values of methods/functions.  They could be polymorphic interfaces, but Object is at the highest levels of abstraction, and is not ideal for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, it would be rare to need to use Object as type parameter. I just didn't understand why at runtime I would get a problem of storing a `void` pointer into an array of `void` pointers. Again, as I said, I would understand if I get a crash later on, I cast this `void` pointer to a `String` and tried to call a `String` method on the cast which is what would happen if I did `strings[0].toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the Object "StringBuilder" to an Array of the object "String". Under some circumstances this might actually work, if you were to assign the StringBuilder Value but I am not to shure about that, as I never used this myself.
Here's a good read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Usually Java takes care of pointers for you which makes it really hard to mess it up.

I hope I could help you :)

Comment: I'm not particularly fussed on the types I've used - I used StringBuilder just because. Let's say I had `String[]` and trying to assign an instance of `class Foo {}`.

Comment: I don't know about C but in Java you need to be strict about your Object types inan Array. Objects have a superclass called Object so you might try to have an array of "Objects" and add a Class to that.